# How to read Html files by using XmlReader

Tags: c#-4.0

I want to read HTML file by using XMLReader. So I wrote some codes, but it throws only XmlException. So please give me any suggestion about how to read the HTML file (and tags) line by line using C#.

```
public class HtmlReader
{
    public List<HtmlDocument> Read(string path)
    {
        List<HtmlDocument> html = new List<HtmlDocument>();
        HtmlDocument h1 = new HtmlDocument();
        using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(path.ToString()))
        {
            try
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    if (reader.IsStartElement())
                    {
                        if (reader.Name == "title" || reader.Name == "body")
                        {
                            switch (reader.Name)
                            {
                                case "title":
                                    if (reader.Read())
                                    {
                                        h1.Title = reader.Value.Trim();
                                    }
                                    break;
                                case "body":
                                    if (reader.Read())
                                    {

                                    }
                                    break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch(XmlException)
            {

            }
            }

        return html;
    }
}
```

}

```
 class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        HtmlReader readerObject = new HtmlReader();
        List<HtmlDocument> employeeCollection = readerObject.Read("E:/workoutsPrograms/ConsoleApplication4/Table.html");
    }
}
```

I tried this, but I was not able to read the Html tags line by line. Apart from my expectation, it throws only Exception.

Answer (score 2):

I find the answer for above question. Following codes you can use.

`XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
            settings.DtdProcessing = DtdProcessing.Ignore;
            settings.IgnoreWhitespace = true;`

XmlRederSettings is enabled set features of XmlReader. In that Html file have DOCTYPe, For that avoid we want use the Dtdprocessing.Ignore.